# Google Chrome doesn't load web page

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I'm facing a weird issue with Google Chrome, that doesn't load a webpage while other browsers do. Here's some more details.

- *mywebsite.com/home* **doesn't load** (in Chrome, loads in Firefox and other browsers)
- *mywebsite.com/settings* **loads**
- If I reload the /home page, I don't see any HTTP calls in the Network tab of the Dev Tools
- If I make a GET call to that page with Postman, I obtain the correct HTML
- I already tried to surf in incognito mode, deleted the cache, cookies, any data saved to the website, nothing worked

I can't really understand what's happening, does anyone have any hint? :)

Thank you

Comment: A link to the webpage you are using would be helpful.

Comment: @RaghuRanganathan unfortunately it happens after an authentication page so I can't provide usernames and passwords

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the webpage you are accessing is only failing on Chrome, have you tried disabling the extensions you are using on Chrome?

Try cycling through your extensions and disabling them one by one to check which one is interfering with the website. If it works, just uninstall the extension or feel free to check what caused the problem.

Comment: Thank you, actually I had an extension enabled in incognito mode as well, and it was interfering with page URLs, and I forgot to disable extensions in my tries. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Also antivirus may cause that. I have same issue with Avast. When turning web protection (web shield) off then Chrome works. That is very obvious because when Google Chrome is loading pages (already for ages) and when I turn web protection off then the web pages start loading instantly without even reloading them! This issue doesn't appear in other browsers.

Comment: Suggestions for a first-poster: Be sure to write complete sentences. Omit personal anecdotes - frame them as explanations instead.

Suggested edits:
Consider temporarily disabling any installed antivirus software. Avast web protection (Web Shield) has been known to affect Chrome without affecting other browsers.